# How can I configure msdropdown to show the text field input upon open?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, msdropdown

I would like to display the very same `textarea` that shows up when I `keydown` any alphanumeric character, as a default and not just when they begin typing!

The reason being; some don't even know that you're able to type until you do so.

Comment: Did you find any solution to your problem?

Comment: I've been looking for the same thing for a while, with no solution so far.

Comment: This does the trick for msDropDown

    `$("#msDDid_titleText:hidden").show().val("").focus();`


So you might want to bind it with onOpen:


`var oHandler = $("#msDDid").data("dd");
             oHandler.addMyEvent('onOpen', function(){
               $("#msDDid_titleText:hidden").show().val("").focus();
             });
             oHandler.addMyEvent('onClose', function(){
               
             });`